# CSS position: sticky and overflow

Tags: css, css-position

Not able to find the solution for this. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to have an element with the `position: sticky` appear with a scrollbar if there is more content then the browser height.

I don't want to use `position: fixed` as it will add additional pain in the neck.

Here is the example of how I would expect it to work:

```css
.placeholder {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="child">
    some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br /> some long text
    <br />

  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/mun133e0/)

Here is example with the `position: sticky` where the `overflow` doesn't do anything:

```css
.placeholder {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="child">
    some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  some long text <br />
  
  </div>  
</div>
```

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ab5u54hh/)

Any explanation / solution appreciated.

**Make sure to use Firefox when testing**

Comment: Here is your problem http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky

Comment: you set top:0 inside a scrolling container . the 0 coordonate scrolls within that container :) take it outside and the float element: https://jsfiddle.net/ab5u54hh/7/ The thing about sticky is that it does interact within the flow and can pushed away when another container comes in place example: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/oxNLBO

Comment: sticky is not absolute nor fixed, it is in the flow ang can get sticked to coordonates untill it has room to stay there ...., this is the tricky part .. it can even float .... so no wonder why it is a birt to handle at first ;)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Not relevant; OP is using Firefox as stated in the question, where `position: sticky;` is supported.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's important to understand that `sticky` elements are first treated like a `relative` element and *then* a `fixed` element (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)). Therefore, you must first look at it like a relative element. If you give a height of 100% to a relative element, then nothing really happens unless its parent element has a defined height.

If you want your sticky element to have a scrollbar too, you must give it a meaningful height. I suggest using viewport height:

```
.child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

For the record - the "stickiness" doesn't appear to be working as expected in either FF or Safari in terms of the element becoming `fixed` during scrolling. I'm not concerning myself with that - just focusing on the overflow issue.

Comment: Your answer helped me thx. in my case I used `max-height: calc(100vh - 80px)` because I stuck it to an element 80px from the top. It also allowed me to scroll the longer content on the right side and still keep the list to the left sticky.

Comment: for me position stikcy doesn't seen to be working in combination with overflow:auto for me

Comment: Three days. Three days I've fought this. Thank you.