# Position sticky and overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, image, overflow, sticky

Position sticky is not working when inside a container with overflow:hidden. The overflow hidden is needed however!

```
 <div class="lg:col-start-7 lg:col-end-13" style="overflow:hidden">
     <div style="min-height:100%;">
      <div class="bg-placeholder-bg w-full" style="position:relative">
          <img src="image:src" style="position: sticky;top: 10px;">
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

EDIT: OK ive just realised this is all wrapped in a container that has and needs overflow:hidden thus why it is not working! Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a working example, Read [mcve]

Comment: Give the parent container with col class an fixed height to see what happens. the min:height is a relative hieght and the question is what is it relative to? the parent height and the parent height is auto as well.

Comment: The only solution I could find was to remove the overflow:hidden!

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed like so:

```css
#mainContent{
height:400vh;
width:100vw;
background-color:blue
overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
height:50vh;
background-color:red;
position:absolute
top:0;
left:0;
}
.bgContainer{
height:10vh;
width:100vw;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
.imgSticky{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0326/7189/t/65/assets/pf-e820b2e0--mother-tree-forest.jpg?v=1619557558");

  }
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">

 <div>
 <div class="container">
      <div class="bgContainer">
         <div class="imgSticky"></div>
    
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: See above update! Its because it is in a container with overflow:hidden;

Comment: In that case you might want to take a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752448/css-position-sticky-and-overflow#answers-header)

Comment: I dont see the answer to my problem there ^

Comment: I edited my answer with the only solution i see, dissociate the main content from this header-like component that you want.