# Accessing Html tags (Table) for Sticky Header

Tags: css, html-table

Sticky Table Header doesn't STICK.

The background color assigned to the Table-thead tag works but the "sticky position" doesn't.

The 2 tries with th:nth-child(1) & th:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n + 9)  both don

***Try:***

```
 "overflow-x:auto" is required to create horizontal scrollbar when the table overflows in the x-direction  

   /* try_1 */
    table thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
    background: green; position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 10;
  }
  /* try_2 */
  table thead tr > th:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n + 9)  {
       position: sticky;top:0;background-color:red; z-index: 10;}
```

***Code:***(Table has been kept short for the sake of brevity.Please add a few more rows to test the code.)

```css
     /* try_1 */
        /* table thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
        background: green; position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 10;
      } */
      /* try_2 */
      table thead tr > th:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n + 9)  {
           position: sticky;top:0;background-color:red; z-index: 10;}
```

```html
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    
        <table border="1" class="dataframe">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: right;">
          <th></th>
          <th>UpdateTime</th>
          <th>StrikePrice</th>
          <th>CallLtp</th>
          <th>CallOi</th>
          <th>PutLtp</th>
          <th>PutOi</th>
          <th>OiTrend</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>0</th>
          <td>14.24</td>
          <td>18050</td>
          <td>0.57</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>-0.58</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>14.25</td>
          <td>18050</td>
          <td>0.57</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>-0.58</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td>14.33</td>
          <td>18050</td>
          <td>-2.44</td>
          <td>0.12</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>0.43</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td>14.31</td>
          <td>18600</td>
          <td>-2.17</td>
          <td>-0.18</td>
          <td>0.92</td>
          <td>-1.4</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>4</th>
          <td>14.31</td>
          <td>18600</td>
          <td>-2.17</td>
          <td>-0.18</td>
          <td>0.92</td>
          <td>-1.4</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>5</th>
          <td>14.31</td>
          <td>18600</td>
          <td>-2.17</td>
          <td>-0.18</td>
          <td>0.92</td>
          <td>-1.4</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `<div>`'s inline style `overflow-x:auto`, both your solutions will work.

```css
/* try_1 */


/* table thead tr:nth-child(1) th{
        background: green; position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 10;
      } */


/* try_2 */

table thead tr>th:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n + 9) {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: right;">
        <th></th>
        <th>UpdateTime</th>
        <th>StrikePrice</th>
        <th>CallLtp</th>
        <th>CallOi</th>
        <th>PutLtp</th>
        <th>PutOi</th>
        <th>OiTrend</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <td>14.24</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>14.25</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>14.33</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>-2.44</td>
        <td>0.12</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.43</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <td>14.24</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>14.25</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>14.33</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>-2.44</td>
        <td>0.12</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.43</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <td>14.24</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>14.25</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>0.57</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>-0.58</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>14.33</td>
        <td>18050</td>
        <td>-2.44</td>
        <td>0.12</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.43</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>14.31</td>
        <td>18600</td>
        <td>-2.17</td>
        <td>-0.18</td>
        <td>0.92</td>
        <td>-1.4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shub thanks for looking into the issue ...but "overflow-x:auto" is required to create  horizontal scrollbar when the table gets stretched in the x-direction .

Comment: @srt111 I don't understand why overflow: auto is required. If you have overflow: visible (the default at least on my browsers) then you will get to be able to scroll if the table is too wide for the viewport, and the sticky works OK.

Comment: Found a solution about `overflow` and `sticky`: [CSS position: sticky and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752448/css-position-sticky-and-overflow#answers-header)